# Unable to copy data from another workbook while in working current sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to compare Cell value from Column A IN active sheet to Column A in closed master workbook ( penn_990_migration_master_plan.xlsx), then once found similar cell in master sheet from Column A  then grab corresponding cell value from C column from master workbook. Put in active sheet under column  H.

```
Sub CompareAndCopy() 
Dim NumberOfValues, NumberOfValues2 As Integer
Dim value1, value2 As String
Dim value3 As Long
Dim i, n, j As Long
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wbsb1, wbsb2 As Worksheet
   
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\excel\01synch\Penn_990_Migration_Master_Plan.xlsx")
    Set wbws2 = wb.Sheets("Master")

NumberOfValues2 = wbws2.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row

NumberOfValues1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("To Be migrated").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
Set wbws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("To Be migrated")
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = 1 To NumberOfValues1
            value3 = 0
            For n = 1 To NumberOfValues2
            value1 = LCase(wbsb1.Range("A" & n).Value)
            value2 = LCase(wbsb2.Range("A" & i).Value)
                      
            If Mid(value2, 1, Len(value1)) = value1 Then
            value3 = value3 + wbsb2.Range("C" & n).Value
            wbsb1.Range("H" & i).Value = value3
            End If
           
            Next

Next
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
wb.Close
    newExcel.Quit
    Set newExcel = Nothing
End Sub
```

But getting message at "Value1 = Lcase(wbsb1.range("A" & n).value" run-time error '424' , object required. any idea what i am missing ??

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo.  What you want it to be ...

[image]

... what you've got/assigned ...

[image]

To help you in the future, put `Option Explicit` at the top of your module.  That will ensure you've correctly initialised all variables.

Comment: Tried to install Rubberduck , but Norton antivirus keep removing it. is there anyother debugger software ? I have also corrected my typo. Now getting "Type mismatch error "  at code "value3 = value3 + wbsb2.Range("C" & n).Value" any idea ?

Comment: got it , column heading was causing mismatch.

Comment: Can you please flag it as the answer? It rewards those who help. Thanks